# Get all products with a specific attribute code with REST API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, api, product-attribute, rest-api

Is there is a built in rest API to get ALL products with a specific `attribute_code`

ex. this API 
https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/:productID
returns

```
..
     <item>
          <attribute_code>featured</attribute_code>
          <value>0</value>
     </item>
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try with Search using REST APIs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html

You should try with GET:

> http://{magento_host}/rest/V1/products?
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=featured&
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=0
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

```
<?php

$userData = ["username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123"];

$ch = curl_init("http://mage215.loc/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);



$ch = curl_init("http://mage215.loc/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=featured&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=0
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); //  method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($emailcontent));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```